# How to assign the output of a command in variable in shell script and use it conditionally

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I am trying to write some conditional script to up my kubernetes system

```
#!/bin/sh

#checking if the namespace exists
export namespace="kube-system"
export mypassword="logan"
#installing json reader
echo mypassword | sudo apt-get install jq
echo mypassword | status=$(sudo kubectl get ns ${namespace} -o json | jq .status.phase -r)
echo "$status" #its not printing

if [ "$status" = "Active" ]
then
   echo hi
else
  echo bye
fi
```

But some how my status variable is not getting printed and neither the if else condition is working ,how to solve it ?Please help

Comment: Do you use `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to replace `echo mypassword` with `echo "$mypassword"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your status assignment (`status=$(...)`) is happening in a subprocess (the one forked to receive the output of `echo mypassword`). So any changes wont reach the running shell.

You need something like:

```sh
# execute a command in a subprocess and capture all output in `status`
status=$(echo ... | sudo kubectl ... | jq ...)
if [ "$status" == 'active' ]
then
   echo 'active'
else
   echo 'not active'
fi
```

Comment: Ohh ok ,so how to solve this ?

Comment: @Cyrus, you quoted the variable $status so that test doesnt break if status is an empty string or is unset, is that right?

Comment: Yes, and to prevent problems when $status contains a string with enclosed spaces (`bash: [: too many arguments`).

Comment: @Cyrus, you are absolutely right; i just thought status would be some enumeration (C identifier-like) string

Comment: Note that one higher level "correct" solution is to stop passing passwords to sudo.  Configure sudo so that is not necessary, or run the entire script via sudo.

Comment: Minor detail: since the original script uses `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`, the single `=` should be used rather than `==` as the argument to `[`. `==` is a bashism.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well test the value with `jq` directly.
When given the `-e` option, `jq` turns boolean values to exit status.

```sh
echo "$mypassword" | sudo kubectl get ns "$namespace" -o json | 
if jq -e '.status.phase == "Active"' >/dev/null
then
  echo hi
else
  echo bye
fi
```